# how to update ng-model value in layout.cshtml in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am creating an eCommerce website in asp.net mvc with angularjs.I add layout page in my application which contains a same header and footer for complete application
here is the link of my online website 
[www.stylesstore.com](http://www.stylesstore.com)

Now i Have to count cart values in my application. I count the items while adding item to cart and trying to update the model of item count. But It is not updating the value in header. But when I add the same model in my cshtml page then it update the model

here is the code which i am using to count items

```
$scope.addToCart = function (Picture1, ProductName, UnitPrice) {
    var count = 0;
    var item = new cartItem(Picture1, ProductName, UnitPrice);
    $scope.items.push(item);
    store.set('StyleStoreCart', $scope.items);
    sharedService.addProduct($scope.items);
    console.log("storegetitems", $scope.getCookies);
    //$scope.Itemcount = $scope.items.length;
    console.log($scope.Itemcount);
    // store.set('itemcount', $scope.Itemcount);
    toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": false,
        "debug": false,
        "newestOnTop": false,
        "progressBar": false,
        "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
        "preventDuplicates": false,
        "onclick": null,
        "showDuration": "300",
        "hideDuration": "1000",
        "timeOut": "5000",
        "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
        "showEasing": "swing",
        "hideEasing": "linear",
        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    }
    toastr.warning('Item Added to Your Cart', 'Cart Update')
}
```

and in my layout page I am using this

```
<div class="header-right" ng-controller="products">
    <ul>
        <li class="phone">+91 99 79 62 1376</li>
        <li class="mail"><a href="mailto:gurpreet.bawa7@gmail.com"> gurpreet.bawa7@gmail.com</a></li>
        <li class="checkout">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="goToCart()">
                <span class="cart">
                    ({{items.length}})
                </span>
                <span class="check">Checkout</span>
            </a>
            @*<div class="shopping">
                <h5>Your Shopping Cart is empty.</h5>
                <p>Give it purpose—fill it with books, movies, mobiles, cameras, toys and fashion jewellery.</p>
            </div>*@
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

can anybody tell me how can I update this header value?
Thanks

Comment: Do yourself the biggest favor and pick exactly **one** templating solution. Either do it all in MVC or do it all in your Angular app. Don't template on both sides. It's just a bad idea.

Comment: okk but if I use only angular then also I have to create single view for header and footer for all pages.. then How can I update that header and footer values please tell me @AndyGaskell